# How to adjust displayed columns of Bokeh DataTable through MultiChoice?

Tags: python, datatable, callback, bokeh

I have a rather large dataframe (60+ columns) that I would like to make easily readable to the user by allowing to select custom columns. I figured out how to adjust the data of the DataTable to the selected columns using a custom CustomJS callback, but can't seem to figure out how to also adjust the displayed columns.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, MultiChoice
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn

import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                     'Age': [10, 20, 30, 40],
                     'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'X', 'Y']})

vars = list(data.columns)
initial_vars = vars[:1]

original_data = ColumnDataSource(data)
source = ColumnDataSource(data[initial_vars])

columns = [TableColumn(field=Ci, title=Ci) for Ci in vars]  # bokeh columns
data_table = DataTable(columns=columns, source=source)  # bokeh table

var_selector_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(original_data=original_data, columns=columns, source=source), code="""    
    var original = original_data.data;
    var data = source.data;
    var data_keys = Object.keys(data)
    var selected_vars = cb_obj.value;
    selected_vars.push('index');

    if (data_keys.length < selected_vars.length) {
        var add_var = selected_vars.filter(nut => !data_keys.includes(nut));
        data[add_var] = original[add_var];
    } else {
        var del_var = data_keys.filter(nut => !selected_vars.includes(nut));
        delete data[del_var];
    }
    source.change.emit();
""")

var_selector = MultiChoice(value=initial_vars, options=vars)
var_selector.js_on_change('value', var_selector_callback)
# nutrient_selector.js_link('value', data_table.columns)

output_file("var_selector.html")
show(column(var_selector, data_table))
```

[image: DataTable Screenshot]

As a result the DataTable displays the data for the selected columns, but unfortunately also displays empty columns for the variables that shouldn't be displayed. Does anybody know how I can get my code to only display the selected columns?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to dynamically change the number of columns in a `DataTable`. What you could do is hide the "Age" column title when the column has no data.

Comment: By hiding, does this mean that the column as such would be hidden as well, or would the result simply be that the columns are still displayed but without any content?

Comment: As I said you can only change the column title, like set it to an empty string, but the column will still be displayed. I don't know any other solution.

Comment: That's of course sad to hear, but thank you for pointing it out and saving me from wasting time on it!